# ¿Cómo puedo sumar los valores de una lista enlazada para despues poder sacar el promedio de la misma y mostrarlo en pantalla?

Tags: c

Este es mi fragmento de código. No sé cómo almacenar los valores de la lista enlazada en un acumulador para luego sacar su promedio e imprimirlo en pantalla.

```
int main(){
    int i, acu=0;
    float prom=0;
    NODO *lista=crearlista(lista);
    srand(time(0));

    printf("Lista Enlazada\n");
    for(i=0;i<10;i++){
        lista = agregarnodo(lista,"%d");
    }
    while(lista!=NULL){
        printf("%d\n",lista->num);
        lista = lista->sig;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: y si creas una funcion llamada suma de tipo float `float suma(lista)` y dentro pones `while (lista != NULL) { suma += lista->num} ` si quieres calcular el promedio seria algo como  `while (lista != NULL) { suma += lista->num; total++}  prom = suma/total`

Comment: Ya tienes escrito un bucle que recorre la lista (donde la imprimes). Dentro del mismo bucle puedes ir sumando los valores que vas encontrando en `lista->num` a la vez que llevas la cuenta de cuántos son. Necesitarás un par de variables más, inicializadas con 0, una para lo que llevas sumado y otra para el contador.

Comment: Algo asi, `while(lista!=NULL){
        printf("%d\n",lista->num);
        lista = lista->sig;
        acu = acu + lista->num;
        total++;
    }
    prom = acu/total;
    printf("El promedio es: %f\n",prom);
`